# TS2339: Property 'Ripple' does not exist on type 'typeof Button'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, reactstrap

I'm trying to use Button.Ripple but I got the error. This is my code:

```js
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

// ** Third Party Components
import { Card, CardBody, Button } from 'reactstrap'

const PreviewActions = ({ id, setSendSidebarOpen, setAddPaymentOpen }) => {
  return (
    <Card className='invoice-action-wrapper'>
      <CardBody>
        <Button.Ripple color='primary' block className='mb-75' onClick={() => setSendSidebarOpen(true)}>
          Send Invoice
        </Button.Ripple>
        <Button.Ripple color='secondary' block outline className='mb-75'>
          Download
        </Button.Ripple>
```

Has anyone faced such an error? How can I solve it?

Comment: `reactstrap` don't have `Button.Ripple`